# Can I rescue out of a UnhandledAlertError?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

If I get an error such as...

```
Modal dialog present: "The data could not be loaded." (Selenium::WebDriver
::Error::UnhandledAlertError)
```

Error Extended

```
     And save the product.
     # features/step_definitions/setup_sd.rb:35
  Modal dialog present: "The data could not be loaded."(Selenium::WebDriver
 ::Error::UnhandledAlertError)
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profi
le20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-p
rocessor.js:12770:in `nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9576:in `Dispatcher.executeAs/<'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9723:in `Resource.prototype.handle'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9670:in `Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:12544:in `WebDriverServer/<.handle'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2054:in `createHandlerFunc/<'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2387:in `ServerHandler.prototype.handleResponse'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1223:in `Connection.prototype.process'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1677:in `RequestReader.prototype._handleResponse'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1525:in `RequestReader.prototype._processBody'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1393:in `RequestReader.prototype.onInputStreamReady'
  [remote server] resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js:394:in `openModalWindow'
  [remote server] resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js:491:in `ModalPrompter.prototype.openPrompt'
  [remote server] resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js:543:in `ModalPrompter.prototype.alert'
  [remote server] file:///C:/Users/blah/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20161219-65588-1gtvf51/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/prompt-service.js:4800:in `ObservingAlert.prototype.alert'
  [remote server] http://10.20.13.39:17007/ScriptResource.axd?d=OwfU9dJwZwohiTGVGwSmnis5Sz77zh88m4xormA1BrE_-VNmQFnovvsDzNzH0qQCr6JjS2t6QbrSRBO86wKNXm1cO31z7GUAtLwQK7eaJqY5kZhHVmGxOxCJOEbh_mzvIE82nn2eWB69U7ZhzAQgCM43cXTVpLMGGjDVeilur_aPJt6ieH-q_9a1xO06Hhnb0&t=5df05159:1:in `_z19F'
  ./features/step_definitions/setup_sd.rb:37:in `/^save the product\.$/'
  features/product_setup/Setup05_template_var_textbox.feature:8:in `And save the product.'
```

can I rescue out?

```
 When(/^save the product\.$/) do
   pf = blah_page.new
   within_frame('blah') do
     sleep(2)
     begin
       find(:css, pf.LOC_BTN_SAVE_BLAH).click
     #rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError #error still raises
     rescue #error still raises
       page.accept_alert
       sleep(0.05)
     end
   end
 end
```

I have been able to rescue out of element_not_found, I was wondering if there is something preventing from rescuing out of this error type as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can rescue that error. But maybe the error is being raised before your rescue block. Does `within_frame('blah') { }` raise it?

Comment: no, the ```find(:css, pf.LOC_BTN_SAVE_BLAH).click``` produces an alert window which raises the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError can definitely be rescued , if you catch it at the end of the block where it was thrown.  Depending on which browser you are using you may (some browsers auto-clear when raising the error) need to clear the alert by calling `page.accept_alert` before continuing on, otherwise the next page action will re-raise the same error.

Comment: sadly the unhandled alert error, went away, so I'll keep a watch and mark this answered as soon as possible.

Comment: Sadly the error is back, even with the fix, I added the entire error.

Comment: @TangibleDream which is line 37 of setup_sd.rb ?

Comment: within_frame('blah') do

Comment: @TangibleDream Then that's the line that's raising the exception, you need to move your rescue outside of the within_frame –  or --  accepting the alert is just causing another alert to open, in which case you need to fix that in your app

Comment: I think that fixed it.  It moved along to the next issue which I think is fixed as well.  Thanks to the sporadic nature of this bug,  I won't know for sure until I witness it being bypassed.  Thanks Thomas